# How to enable default-http-backend in Kubernetes in order to make Ingress work?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I have a single node Kubernetes instance from [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/). It is installed on a Ubuntu Server 20.20 running on Raspberry Pi 4.

I am tring to setup an ingress resource which cannot get working.

When I run `kubectl describe ingress my-ingress` I get this output

```
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
```

From what I found in the internet, `default-http-backend` is something that should have been there by default, but when I run `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` I don't see it.

**Question:** How to enable `default-http-backend` in mikrok8s? Or more generally, how do I make ingress work?

Note: Ingress and DNS addons are enabled.

Comment: How did you create your `deployment` and `service`? Using selectors or `headless`? Could you share your YAMLs (deployment, svc, ingress)?

Comment: @PjoterS my configuration looks exactly like this one (just placeholders are filled): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shpota/cde/master/k8s/resources.yml

Comment: It seems you are using `selectors`, however you are also using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` which is supported only when you are using `Nginx Ingress`. Also I am not sure if `rewrite` is supported on MicroK8s. Did you try to remove this annotation and use example from [docs](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-ingress) ?

Comment: @PjoterS thank you. The configuration is 100% working (at least it was 6 month ago). Back then, I tested it on a mikrok8s installed on a Ubuntu laptop. This time I try to run it on a Raspberry Pi. For sure, the version of mikrok8s is probably different now, but theoretically it should work the same way. The weird thing is that the config from the doc shows the same error **but works well**. I don't understand why. At the same time, if I try to set path to something else except the root path it gives me 404 (I am checking with `curl 127.0.0.1:80/new-path`). Any ideas?

Comment: @PjoterS I guess the issue was in using `v1beta1` API version. After I changed my Ingress configuration to [this one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) it worked. Though I cannot understand why something that worked half a year ago doesn't work now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested this behavior on my cluster. When I tried configuration provided by you I got below `Warning`:

```
@microk8s:~$ microk8s kubectl get ing
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
```

Also if you will describe it you will get the same `Warning`.

```
@microk8s:~$ kk describe ing
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
Name:             hello-ing
Namespace:        default
Address:          
    Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /hello   hello-svc:80   10.1.128.202:8080)
```

There is similar [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5525) question regarding this error.

> The output you see is just a default for when there is no default backend
> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/describe.go#L2393

However, it's working normally.

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1/hello
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: hello-647c466dbc-99rml
```

If you would add [default backend](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-backend) you would get output like:

```
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
Name:             ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          127.0.0.1
Default backend:  test2:80   10.1.128.205:80)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /hello   hello-svc:80   10.1.128.204:8080)
```

and `Ingress` looks like:

```
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: test2
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

**Though I cannot understand why something that worked half a year ago doesn't work now.**

As new `apiVersion` changes a bit syntax, adding some features, parameters, etc, there might be situation when after update/upgrade some resources cannot be validated anymore by `Kubernetes`. As stated in [this article](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-apiversion-definition-guide.html).

> An object definition in Kubernetes requires an apiVersion field. When Kubernetes has a release that updates what is available for you to use—changes something in its API—a new apiVersion is created.
> However, the official Kubernetes documentation provides little guidance on apiVersion. This guide gives you a cheat sheet on which version to use, explains each version, and gives you the timeline of releases.

If you would only change apiVersion in your YAML, you would get error:

```
error: error validating "ingress.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field "serviceName" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend, ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field "servicePort" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

To sum up, you got this `<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>` as there was no `default backend` configured.

For more details you can check [Kubernetes Api Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/).

Answer (score 11):

The [default backend](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-rules) is a fallback for when the ingress controller cannot match any of the rules.

### `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`

```yaml
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: tea-svc
      port:
        number: 80
```

Here is a complete example using `v1`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: tea-svc
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - host: cafe.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: tea-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

### `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`

Depending on the `apiVersion` of your yaml file, the default backend is specified in a different format.  It looks like you are using the beta format.

```yaml
spec:
    backend:
        serviceName: tea-svc
        servicePort: 80
```

The NGINX Ingress Controller complains about `v1beta1`, so far it works in kubernetes 1.21.2, but as the warning says it won't soon:

```
networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
```